# Bash code to split every 4th line and then merge

Tags: bash, merge, split

Maybe my title cannot fully explain my intention.
I have a list of data like below:

```
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/1
TGTCTAGTTTTTATAGGAAGATATTTCCTTTTCTACCTTTGACTTCAAAGCGGCTGAAATCTCCACTTGCAAATTCCACAAAAAGAGTGTTACAAGTCT
+
Yeeeeeeeeeceed]dddddd^YdceeeedaeeddYccccc\ddceeYeYY`[`bcYc^_XY^_]d^dd`abdddee\e\ddLb]`_`cTbbbYbaM_]
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/2
TTTGTAAAGTCTGCACGTGGATAACTTGACCACTTAGAGGCCTTCGTTGGAAACGGGTTTTTTTCATGTAAGGCTAGACAGAAGAATTCTCAGTAACTTCAAGTTACTGAGAATTCTTCTGTCTAGCCTTACATGAAAAAAACCCGTTTCCAACGAAGGCCTCTAAGTGGTCAAGTTATCCACGTGCAGACTTTACAAA
+
ffcaefffcdeeeeeeeeeedff^f`\\eeedaec^d^d`deaffeeTecb^bbbddadYcccW[X\MZ\XaU_UTI\]TZ]K[VQX^aIb`b`^X^YSYHWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0
```

We can see the first line and 5th line are both head/name, but ending with either #0/1 or #0/2. Now I hope to group every 4 lines, but later merge all those with #0/1 together, and #0/2 together.

Should be like:

```
@HWI....#0/1
TTCCGC
+
cffccc
@HWI....#0/1
CCGGGG
+
abbcgg
....
```

also another file is:
@HWI....#0/1
    ATTCCG
    +
    fccfcc
    @HWI....#0/1
    CGCCGG
    +
    gbbcaa

I know how to do this with a simple python script. But just wondering if we can do only with some quite simple bash code?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed -n '1,${p;n;n;n;}'` should work for getting every 4th line:

```
[ 11:32 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/bash ]$ cat blah | sed -n '1,${p;n;n;n;}'
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/1
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/2

[ 11:33 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/bash ]$ cat blah
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/1
TGTCTAGTTTTTATAGGAAGATATTTCCTTTTCTACCTTTGACTTCAAAGCGGCTGAAATCTCCACTTGCAAATTCCACAAAAAGAGTGTTACAAGTCT
+
Yeeeeeeeeeceed]dddddd^YdceeeedaeeddYccccc\ddceeYeYY`[`bcYc^_XY^_]d^dd`abdddee\e\ddLb]`_`cTbbbYbaM_]
@HWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0/2
TTTGTAAAGTCTGCACGTGGATAACTTGACCACTTAGAGGCCTTCGTTGGAAACGGGTTTTTTTCATGTAAGGCTAGACAGAAGAATTCTCAGTAACTTCAAGTTACTGAGAATTCTTCTGTCTAGCCTTACATGAAAAAAACCCGTTTCCAACGAAGGCCTCTAAGTGGTCAAGTTATCCACGTGCAGACTTTACAAA
+
ffcaefffcdeeeeeeeeeedff^f`\\eeedaec^d^d`deaffeeTecb^bbbddadYcccW[X\MZ\XaU_UTI\]TZ]K[VQX^aIb`b`^X^YSYHWI-ST150_0129:3:8:21208:93107#0
```

[Useful One-Line Scripts For `sed`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)
[`man sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Comment: @sputnick Yea, I know `sed -n '1,${p;n;n;n;}' FILE` works just as well but its such habit by now to `cat` everything =p.  It's not as bad as `cat FILE | less` though =p.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you, however getting every 4th line is trivial with GNU sed:

```
sed '1~4!d' file
```

To `group` four lines, by which I presume you mean reduce 4 lines to one:

```
sed '/#0\/[12]$/{N;N;N;s/\n//;d}' file
```

This uses the regex which you mentioned above i.e. a line ending in `#0/1` or `#0/2`